# The insertdata does not prevent the error 500 primary key constraint

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, landing-page

I have come across a scenario in the landing page, where **insertdata** helps in the addition of the data from cloud page in the intended data extension.
But if I refresh the same landing page, I get error 500, PK violation, since it cannot insert a duplicate record.

I want to use the data extension as the entry source of a journey builder. Thus, I need to keep a primary key in the data extension.

If I do not give the primary key, then I would have to keep the setting as NO RETRY in the journey builder. However the data extension will have duplicates, which I do not want.

I tried to update the function as **upsertdata**, it didn't work out for this specific scenario.

Any suggestions to handle this scenario in the landing page.

Comment: have you considered doing a lookup to the DE to see if the record exists then levergaging an if/then logic